# Is there a convenient GUI tool for configuring Marlin settings?

Tags: marlin, g-code, software

I am looking for a tool to configure various runtime settings of Marlin firmware (e.g. bed leveling) that would be accessible from a computer rather than from the LCD menu on the printer.

In a slightly similar vein I found [this marlin-config tool from github user akaJes](https://github.com/akaJes/marlin-config). However, this tool configures build-time settings of the firmware (e.g. which menus to include in the first place into the build) whereas I'm looking for something that controls the settings and printer when the firmware has already been uploaded.

The main goal in my search is discoverability - I know I can find the appropriate G-codes for whatever I want to change, but I don't necessarily always know in advance that a given setting exists in the first place.